# Write a Java method that will remove a given character from a string objec

Tags: java

We can use the replaceAll method to replace all of the occurrences of a string with another string. The important point to note is that replaceAll() accepts String as argument, so you can use the Character class to create a string and use it to replace all the characters with an empty string.

Comment: What's the issue you are having? Your question states you have a problem getting x and y values of an object but how so? Also your comments in code state everything works above the calls to player.collect(...), will need to explain and see the player class code to see what's wrong if that is your issue

Comment: i added the player class . my question is that when i invoke collect method from game class ( i pass dot1 as parameter, this line of code was given by our tutor to include in soln) , how do i get the x and y coordinates stored in dot 1 . also how can compare the current postion of the player and coordinates of the dot1(1,1) ??

Comment: Just a reminder - when displaying your code, please make sure it is formatted properly so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion, we can have some stages into the program. Let's go to untie your issue, for example for your code.

```
class Player {

    int id;
    String name;

    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    public Player(int x, int y){
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
    }

    public void collect(Dot d){

    }
    public void move(int dx, int dy){

    }
}
```

Also, we need to build:

```
class Dot {
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    public Dot(int x, int y){
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
    }

}
```

Now, your code will pass the coordinate for Player.

Comment: thank you so much for replying back , i am having a look at your code right now

Comment: but unfortunately i had the player class already according to how out tutor demand us to make one. it is just i cant understand how show i pass an object ( dot1) as input while calling for a 'collect ()' method and then extract x and y coordinate from (dot1) in 'collect()' method to compare these coordinates with that of the player

Answer (score -1):

Based on your updated comments you can get x and y values from your Dot object by simply using dot notation on the Dot Object passed to your method. Updated your "collect" method and added comments to method passed on your requirements:

```
//Inside of player class
    /**
 * Add a “collect()” method to the Player class to collect the dot specified as the parameter 
 * if that is possible. The player can collect a dot only if the player is at the same position as the dot. When 
 * the player collects a dot, the player’s “collectedDots” count should be increased by 1. When the player 
 * collects a dot, the dot should disappear. To implement that, as part of the “collect()” method in the class 
 * Player, there should be a call to a “disappear()” method in the class Dot.
 */
public void collect(Dot dot){
    if(this.xCoordinate == dot.getX() && this.yCoordinate == dot.getY()){
        //increment the players count
        setCollectedDots(getCollectedDots() + 1);

        //remove the dot
        dot.disappear();
    }
}
```

Added method to for disappearing a Dot(assuming to remove the dot from play)

```
public class Dot {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Dot(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the full coordinates for the Dot[x,y]
     * @return
     */
    public int[] getCoordinates(){
        int[] coordinates = new int[2];
        //place our coordinates into the array
        coordinates[0] = x;
        coordinates[1] = y;

        return coordinates;
    }

    public void disappear(){
        //remove from the dot grid by setting to a negative position
        setX( -(this.x));
        setY(-(this.y));
    }

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @param x the x to set
     */
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y
     */
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * @param y the y to set
     */
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also make note of proper formatting, it makes the code harder to understand/read when the formatting is off.